# Grouped NSOutlineView: always expand top level groups?

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsoutlineview

I have a grouped `NSOutlineView` using the sourcelist style to achieve a similar look as Mail.app.

My problem is that the top level groups always start out collapsed so that only the group header rows are visible and no contents.

Instead I'd like the top level groups to always be expanded:

[image: NSOutlineView]

I tried overriding `NSOutlineViewDelegate.outlineView(,shouldExpandItem)` and `NSOutlineView.isItemExpanded()`, but those are not called when the initial contents are loaded, only upon user interaction.

Comment: There's no property to that. Have you simply tried programmatically expanding the top level items after the contents is initially loaded?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Doing that is tricky, because there is no good way to know when the outline view finished reloading its data. `reloadData` is done on the next runloop cycle. I've not found a reliable way to know when the outline view is ready.

Comment: In the list delegate, hook the creation of new views (`tableView:rowViewForRow:`), and if it's a root group row, dispatch a block to expand it.